# Why can you send out ether tokens more than your balance?

Tags: token, ethereum

This is a question about cryptocurrency,based on ether.
[Please go to this site](https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x7E5F4552091A69125d5DfCb7b8C2659029395Bdf)

When we look at Erc20 (WLST),there were 1 million in,yet 101 million out,how could this be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The total supply of WLST is 1,219,746,600,000,000 WLST. You can check it [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0xd7b06571942f1c76ceda0e26db8dd4c1acb59cbf).

Comment: I mean when the owner transfer 101 million WLST out,his balance is 1 million,there were not enough WLST to send out.